# Azure Monitor Export to a SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-monitoring

I need the near real-time front end data from a web app for use in PowerBI. I need to keep this data forever.

I would like to automatically export the App customEvents and pageViews tables for this purpose.

It seems like I need to go from Azure Logs -> Azure Storage Account -> Azure SQL Server -> PowerBI

The steps I'm having trouble with are going from Logs to storage, and then getting the data that's passed into there into a SQL server.

Comment: What do you mean with *I need the near real-time front end data from a web app for use in PowerBI*. You want to **stream** the logs to the dashboard **and store** it forever?

Answer (score 1):

To send logs to Storage Accounts, Event Hubs and Log Analytics, go to the App Service and on the left panel select `Diagnostic setting` and click on `+ Diagnostic settings`.

Select the options which are shown in below image to store the logs in Storage account and click on Save.

[image]

You can now use **Azure Data Factory service to copy the logs from Azure Storage account to Azure SQL Database.**

Please refer this tutorial from Microsoft – [Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL Database by using the Copy Data tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool) to implement the same.

Once data available in Database, we are good to use Power BI to read the data.
Open the Power BI dashboard and click on `Get data from another source ->`.

[image]

Select `Azure` -> `Azure SQL Database` and click on **Connect**.

[image]

Give the server’s name.

[image]

In the next step just give the username and password for your account and you will get the access.

Now you can select the data from any table and showcase it in Power BI dashboard as per of your requirement.